# Python version in virtualenv - ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I have got python2.7 (initiated by python2), python3.5(initiated by python3) and python3.7 (initiated by python3.7)installed
I have installed `virtualenv` from `pip3` (pip3.6 and pip3.7 cannot be found for some reason)

then I created a new folder, setup `virtualenv` include the system site packages in this folder then activated the virtual environment.
I found out I actually have all these three python versions in my virtual environment.
Is it normal? So all system python version will be included in the virtual environment?
Is it possible just nominated one?
When I use `which pythonX`(X is the version number) system shows both python2 and python3.7 are sitting in `/usr/bin/pythonX` folder, but when I did `which python3`, it shows python3 in virtual environment bin folder.

Comment: what do you mean by _ I found out I actually have all these three python version in my virtual environment. _?

Comment: I though when we setup virtualenv, there is only one base version of python will be installed in virtual environment, which is in new created virtual environment folder.

Comment: did you activate the virtual environment using `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate`?

Comment: Yes I did. while command I used is   . ~/.path/to/venv/bin/activate

Comment: when you run `which python` is the path to your virtual environment shown?

Comment: Yes, I have got three python versions shown up. One of them is under environment path. The other two are under system user bin folder.